# Loading ActiveTcl 8.6 to Python 2.7.10 OS X El Capitan (v10.11)

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

Opened a shell in Python, received warning message that Apple's version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) "in use may be unstable." Followed prompts to fix this and (thought) I had successfully upgraded to ActiveTcl 8.6. But it seems that Python is still not linking to ActiveTcl 8.6.

The ActiveTcl executables (wish, tclsh and tkcon) are installed in /usr/local/bin which is per [ActiveState's Installation Guide](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.6/at.install.html).

Yet, [Python's advisory](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) that flags the potential instability of  and provides the link to ActiveState for downloading Active's Tcl/Tk 8.6 explains that Python looks first in /Library/Frameworks for Tcl and Tk frameworks.

Drilling down on /Library/Frameworks confirms updated Tcl.framework and Tk.framework libraries.

Yet, when I now open Python shells, the same...

> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.

Assume this is evidence that Python is not dynamically linking to upgraded 8.6, right?

Ideas, please?

Comment: The page you link to, https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ , says to use tcl/tk 8.5.18.0, not 8.6.whatever, because the PSF-supplied python binary is compiled to link with 8.5 and will not work with (link to) 8.6.whatever.  For 3.6, the python.org binary will almost certainly work with (and only with) 8.6 and if necessary, install 8.6, just as the Windows installer does.  I believe there are other binaries available now that are compiled against 8.6 if you really want or need it.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks, Terry. So, I downloaded 8.5 and am still getting the same warning on opening Python shells.

Comment: Perhaps there is something about installing the replacement that is not properly spelled out.  I know people have done it, but I have not.  If no answer here, try python-list.  When working, It is easily to access without sub via news.gmane.org newsgroup gmane.comp.python.general.  (Some python.org lists don't seem to be working properly at the moment.)